# Feynman:"Tangent is the mean proportional between the two parts of the diameter cut by an equal chord"

Tags: geometry, definition

I cribbed this from Feynman http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_07.html
Here's the situation: We have a Commie Rusky cosmonaut traveling along $x$, just fast enough to evade the Western imperialist law of gravity.  Find how fast, in capitalist units, he is traveling.

In presenting a derivation, Feynman promulgates:

> Now, if we use one of those wonderful theorems in geometry, which says that our tangent is the mean proportional between the two parts of the diameter cut by an equal chord, we see that the horizontal distance travelled is the mean proportional between the 16 feet fallen and the 8000-mile diameter of the earth.

I can look at the diagram (reproduced and attached) and figure out the value of $x$, but I do not understand Feynman's language in stating the theorem.  Can someone please explain the meaning, in this context, of "mean proportional" and "cut by an equal chord"?

I am curious to know if this language is familiar to most (American educated) mathematicians.

[image]

> Acceleration toward the center of a circular path. From plane geometry,
>
> $$\frac{x}{S}=\frac{2R-S}{x}\approx\frac{2R}{x},$$
>
> where $R$ is the radius of the earth, 4000 miles; $x$ is the distance “travelled horizontally” in one second; and $S$ is the distance “fallen” in one second (16 feet).

Comment: I _think_ that [this is the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) that he's referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help to include the *caption* of the figure:

> Fig. 7–4. Acceleration toward the center of a circular path. From
>   plane geometry, $x/S=(2R−S)/x=2R/x$, where $R$ is the radius of the
>   earth, $4000$ miles; $x$ is the distance “travelled horizontally” in
>   one second; and $S$ is the distance “fallen” in one second ($16$
>   feet).

So the "wonderful theorem" is the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) mentioned by Arthur in comments beneath the OP. See also the [proofwiki definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Geometric_Mean/Mean_Proportional) of the term.

Comment: One part I'm still uncertain about is what he means by "cut by an equal chord".  The only thing I can find on "equal chord" is when two chords are compared in length.  Perhaps Feynman means a chord which is divided equally by the diameter?  BTW, I had intended to include the caption.  I guess I forgot to paste it.  I still have it formatted in LyX.  Will fix the OP.

Comment: @StevenHatton, if you extend the (horizontal) dotted line all the way to the circle on the left, it becomes a chord, bisected by the (vertical) diameter, with equal halves.

Comment: That may well be what Feynman meant, but can you provide any other example where someone uses words comparable to "two parts of the diameter cut by an equal chord" to mean the chord is perpendicular to the diametric line segment?  I'm about ready to call BS on Feynman.

Comment: You should post your question in the [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com), Steven! I'm also curious if this is common at all or it is an (unnecesarily) jargonistic wording of Feynman.